# Jquery ajax error 0 on Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I got some weird ajax error in Firefox which i didn't get when i use google chrome:

[image]

here's my ajax code that catch this error:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, opt, thrownError) {
            swal({
                title: xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText,
                //text: "Error requesting : " + opt.url +" "+ thrownError,
                text: xhr.responseText,
                type: "error",
                timer: 15000
            });
            submit.removeClass('m-loader m-loader--right m-loader--light').attr('disabled', false);
        });
```

here's the screenshot of the response if needed:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping your AJAX call inside a `$( document).ready(function() { });` function.